# WPF анимация по смещению изображений

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь создать такой эффект как тут ru.4game.com/lineage2/install (при использовании колеса мышки картинки разделяются) Создала несколько картинок, разрезала их и при нажатии на кнопку хочу получить такой эффект, но работает он только с двумя (прокручивает одну на другую и потом меняет опять на первую со второй) Как сделать с остальными?

```
private void AnimUp(Image img) 
{ 
im4_4.Margin = new Thickness(673, 686, -5, -686); 
var animUp = new ThicknessAnimation(); 
var animUp1 = new ThicknessAnimation(); 
if (img.Margin == new Thickness(673, 0, -4, 0)) 
{ 
animUp.To = new Thickness(673, -688, -4, 0); 
animUp1.To = new Thickness(673, 0, -4, 0); 
} 
animUp.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); 
animUp1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); 
img.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animUp); 
im4_4.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animUp1); 
} 
private void AnimDw(Image img) 
{ 
im4.Margin = new Thickness(0, -687, 0, 0); 
var animDw = new ThicknessAnimation(); 
var animDw1 = new ThicknessAnimation(); 
if (img.Margin == new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)) 
{ 
animDw.To = new Thickness(0, 687, 0, -687); 
animDw1.To = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0); 
} 
animDw.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); 
animDw1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500); 
img.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDw); 
im4.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, animDw1); 
} 
private void btnSlide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
AnimDw(im5); 
AnimUp(im5_5); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте картинки подложки (изначально скрыты). Как только анимация закончилась, вы устанавливаете на подложки нужное изображение и отображаете, а картинки, с которыми проводилась анимация скрываете. Когда они скрыты, возвращаете в исходные  координаты. Перед следующей анимацией, процедура повторяется. Подложки скрываем, а рабочие показываем и запускаем анимацию.
Пользователь ничего не заметит, а вы получите нужный эффект.